# Logic at a low framerate with interpolated rendering at higher framerate

Tags: 3d, optimization, frame-rate, fixed-timestep

It takes too much processing power to do game logic on every rendered frame (60fps), so what if I made my game save frames?

It would actually calculate important stuff 20 times a second, and the render loop just interpolates the 2 frames in-between to make it look like 60fps.

Is this a good idea for improving game performance?

Comment: Profile, profile and profile.

Comment: This is the basic idea behind Fix Your Timestep - https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/ - although the objective is timer stability rather than performance. Regarding performance, engineering for performance is not the same thing as optimization, and while premature optimization etc remains true, it's never too early to engineer for performance. Make sensible performance-related decisions from the outset and you may not even need to optimize at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. Some games do just that.

Even more, they run at constant (e.g. 10) fps for game logic and render at whatever fps they can. Solves whole bunch of problems between machines with different processing powers.